# Can I perform cross correlation on non-stationary data?

Tags: stationarity, cross-correlation

I have level data which need different level of integration to be stationary. I would like to know how to perform a correlation analysis. Can I perform this on raw data or must the data be stationary?

Comment: You can still calculate the sample correlation for time series $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ if they are non-stationary. However, the two time series must be _cointegrated_. If yes, the sample correlation will be a consistent estimator of the true correlation.

Comment: @stans-ReinstateMonica, I wonder if true correlation for cointegrated processes might be dependent on time and approaching 1 or -1 as the length of the time series grows. If so, what is the sample correlation estimating consistently? The correlation for that particular sample size? Would you have a reference?

Comment: These questions are part of very standard time series knowledge, which has been available to humankind for decades. Please see Green or Hamilton... What I have stated to you is correct.

Comment: @stans, here is a simulation in R illustrating the distribution of sample cross correlation of two cointegrated processes when the true correlation between their innovations is approximately zero: 
`Ts=c(30,100,300,1000,3000);
m=1000;
XCor=matrix(NA,ncol=length(Ts),nrow=m);

for(j in 1:length(Ts)){
 for(i in 1:m){
  set.seed(i    ); x=cumsum(rnorm(Ts[j]));
  set.seed(i+1e6); y=x+rnorm(Ts[j]);
  XCor[i,j]=cor(x,y);
 };
};

for(j in 1:length(Ts)){
 plot(density(XCor[,j]));
 readline();
}` If you run it, you will see that it contradicts your statement but does not contradict mine.

Comment: @stans-ReinstateMonica, given the simulation evidence, I am curious about a precise reference in those classical textbooks contradicting it.

Comment: And did you let the sample size converge to infinity? Consistency means n----> inf. With all respect, and with warmest wishes, what I have stated is quite standard. Again: Greene or Hamilton... I would love to engage in a debate with you regarding some other, more sophisticated and unresolved matters, like gradient boosting versus deep learning. Warmest regards.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, in presence of nonstationarity, cointegration is one of two situations that are possible, so it is relevant enough, I guess. stans mentioned it, and I chipped in to point out some false statements.

Comment: @RichardHardy I’m afraid, your simulation describes a different problem. By design, you are making the true correlation between $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ change over time in the regression equation $Y(t) = X(t) + \varepsilon(t)$. Naturally, if there is “no true correlation” (loosely speaking), if the correlation is constantly changing then there is nothing to estimate consistently. However, if the true correlation is constant, the estimate will be consistent... You may ask, which two non-stationary process could possibly have constant correlation? Are they not supposed to explode over time? (cont.)...

Comment: ... Well, not necessarily. Imagine four independent stationary processes: $U(t)$, $V(t)$, $Q(t)$ and $W(t)$. Let's say all of them have unit standard deviations and zero means. Further, ${\rm corr}(U(t-1),U(t)) = \eta\neq\gamma = {\rm corr}(V(t-1),V(t))$. Next, let us define a somewhat strange process $Z(t)$: $Z(t) = U(t)$, $t = 1,...,10$, $21,...,30,$ $41,...,50,...$; $Z(t) = V(t), t = 11,...,20,$ $31,...,40,$ $51,...,60,...$. Process $Z(t)$ is non-stationary but non-explosive, nonetheless. Finally, as you can guess, $X(t) = a Z(t) + Q(t)$ and $Y(t) = a Z(t) + W(t)$. (cont.)...

Comment: ... $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are cointegrated non-stationary processes. Their correlation is constant and equals $\rho = a^2 / [a^2 + 1]$. The regression equation equals $Y(t) = \rho X(t) + \varepsilon(t)$ and $\rho$ is estimated consistently by the sample correlation... I take back some of what I’ve said. Thank you for your comments. They made me think more deeply about the problem.

Comment: @stans, so what do you take back? *I’m afraid, your simulation describes a different problem*. No, this is incorrect. What you subsequently describe is characteristic to cointegrated processes - see my first comment. Also, your $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are not cointegrated because they are not integrated to begin with, hence your argument breaks down.

Comment: @RichardHardy I was using term "cointegration" in the wide sense: two processes are non-stationary but their linear combination is stationary (something which is done in finance, somewhat loosely, I guess). You want "cointegration" to be used in the narrow sense (two processes are $I(1)$ but their linear combination is $I(0))$? Fine. Let's make $Z(t) = t + U(t)$. Now $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ are $I(1)$... In this case the sample correlation is calculated on the detrended data but consistent estimation of the true correlation is still possible, for these  two so non-stationary processes. (cont.)...

Comment: ... Also please note that OP's question implies that there exists a constant correlation, which is possible. Hence your simulation, which has violated the assumption, corresponds to a different problem... More importantly, I hope you've read my argument fully and see what I am trying to say. I do see what you have been saying... I take a couple of my sentences back in the sense that this discussion turned out to be more interesting and informative than what I had originally expected. And for this I am thankful to your comments. Also thanks for checking the mathematics of my argument.

Comment: @stans-ReinstateMonica, *You want "cointegration" to be used in the narrow sense*: whether I want it or not, I am using the well established notions of integration and cointegration; see Hamilton or Greene, or any time series textbook for that matter. Meanwhile, your use of terminology is clashing with the established one. Hence, you may wish to create your own terms to avoid ambiguity. Regarding your new example, adding a deterministic time trend to a stationary variable does not make it integrated. Also, in my eyes the OP does not even remotely imply that there exists a constant correlation.

Comment: @RichardHardy Adding a determinstic trend to a stationary process _does_ make it integrated. For example, this Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration) says: "In statistics, the order of integration, denoted $I(d)$, of a time series is a summary statistic, which reports the minimum number of differences required to obtain a _covariance-stationary series_"... Of course, OP's problem implied constant correlation. The whole premise of frequentist point estimation is that the parameter is constant but unknown. Of course, one cannot estimate something which does no exist.

Comment: @RichardHardy Cointegration is usually considering nonstationarity in terms of acumulating shocks, however some authors also use "common trend" idea without specifying what kind of trend we are talking about. At the end of the day if Y(t) = aX(t) + e(t) can be satisfied if common trend can be cancelled out. In that case I believe "a" can be estimated.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, thanks for you input. I am too busy to deal with this rigorously (by posting an answer myself), but I have spent some effort on not leaving misleading statements unchallenged out here on CV.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* calculate correlation for non-stationary variables, but you have to think carefully about *why* you are doing so and what you hope to learn.  As @stans-ReinstateMonica suggested, reading up on co-integration would be a good start.

As @RichardHardy points out, one problem is that your estimates will depend on your estimation window.  Imagine we have two integrated processes that are just straight lines through the origin with opposite slopes. Their correlation is -1.  Now add some shared stationary noise to each of them, and the correlation will increase towards 1 as the variance of the noise becomes large relative to the variance of the lines.  Unfortunately, that variance is proportional to the square of the width of the observation window, so changing the window changes the correlation.

Because of problems like this, I find it hard to think of examples where calculating the correlation of nonstationary variables would be useful.  If in doubt I suggest you difference for stationarity but, as always in statistics, in the answer to what you should calculate should be determined by the inference you wish to draw from the result.

Comment: *the correlation will increase towards 1 as the variance of the noise becomes large relative to the variance of the lines*: perhaps *small* rather than *large*? Also, a straight line is not a representative example of an integrated process.

Comment: No, I do mean large -- the noise is shared so when it is large correlation approaches 1.  Straight lines are just a simple example to illustrate.

Comment: Missed the word "shared" initially, my bad.